# What could cause element not clickable while it is the same element?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

An img `WebElement` click rarely fails claiming the Element is not clickable even though the element that would get the click is the same.

I have a dialog that contains some button (close button with img X inside of it).

When I try to click the close the dialog by clicking on the `WebElement` for the img, rarely, I'd get `WebDriverException` as follows:

> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element
>
> `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAQAAAC1+jfqAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAAAmJLR0QAAKqNIzIAAAAJcEhZcwAACxIAAAsSAdLdfvwAAAAHdElNRQfhCB8QKRBsEUJwAAAAn0lEQVQoz72RMQ7CMAwADwbgCSyhqmDpFj6AWqSOfIoH8BkGNsLGhiwG6NKJDvwBBoaExPCAeontu0SWA32F1HKTRawyucjK58PQ21LgvCIZjiU7DwbhzpQjBR0lbxw5LaXtlKCUl8ZKiAoapxkARkzCOU7NKMiMEzktdwxO5n9CxBVrGq18Xzh4bB/2SUWDYf+7qI1cxaRx5Sx1b7/0AYDRNbDgNXvDAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" class="gwt-Image" style="visibility: visible;">` is not clickable at point (834, 307). Other element would receive the click:
>
> `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAQAAAC1+jfqAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAAAmJLR0QAAKqNIzIAAAAJcEhZcwAACxIAAAsSAdLdfvwAAAAHdElNRQfhCB8QKRBsEUJwAAAAn0lEQVQoz72RMQ7CMAwADwbgCSyhqmDpFj6AWqSOfIoH8BkGNsLGhiwG6NKJDvwBBoaExPCAeontu0SWA32F1HKTRawyucjK58PQ21LgvCIZjiU7DwbhzpQjBR0lbxw5LaXtlKCUl8ZKiAoapxkARkzCOU7NKMiMEzktdwxO5n9CxBVrGq18Xzh4bB/2SUWDYf+7qI1cxaRx5Sx1b7/0AYDRNbDgNXvDAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" class="gwt-Image" style="visibility: visible;">`

As you can see the elements are identical. I started to doubt the Staleness of the element, its enablement, and even the possibility that the element [moves](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/help/clicking-issues).

Below is a code snippet that includes debugging message when I will explain.

```java
private static final By X_BUTTON__SELECTOR
    = WlSeleniumUtils.selectTagWithClass("img", "gwt-Image");

public void clickAndReturnIfAny() {
   WebElement closeImage = manageWorkspaceDialogWebElem
     .findElement(X_BUTTON__SELECTOR);

   // print the elements location before clicking
   System.out.println(String.format
     ("Position: %s, Dimensions: %s", 
      closeImage.getLocation() + "", 
      closeImage.getSize() + ""));
   try {

     // print check for staleness and enablement.
     System.err.println
         ("close button: stale? "
          + driverHelper.isStale(closeImage)
          + " displayed? " + closeImage.isDisplayed()
          + " enabled? " + closeImage.isEnabled()
          + " clickable? " + (ExpectedConditions
                              .elementToBeClickable
                              (closeImage)
                              .apply(driverHelper.getDriver())
                              != null));
     closeImage.click();
   }
   catch (WebDriverException wde) {
     System.err.println
         ("Faied to click manage-workspaces dialog's "
          + "close button: stale? "
          + driverHelper.isStale(closeImage)
          + " displayed? " + closeImage.isDisplayed()
          + " enabled? " + closeImage.isEnabled()
          + " clickable? " + (ExpectedConditions
                              .elementToBeClickable
                              (closeImage)
                              .apply(driverHelper.getDriver())
                              != null));

     // print the entire HTML content to check for multiple img tags.
     System.err.println
         (manageWorkspaceDialogWebElem.getAttribute("innerHTML"));

     // fetch the element again and check its location
     closeImage = manageWorkspaceDialogWebElem
         .findElement(X_BUTTON__SELECTOR);
     System.out.println(String.format
             ("Position: %s, Dimensions: %s",
              closeImage.getLocation() + "",
              closeImage.getSize() + ""));

     throw new RuntimeException
         ("Failed to close mange-workspaces dialog.", wde);
   }
}
```

Before executing the click:

> Position: (826, 299), Dimensions: (16, 16)
>
> close button: stale? false displayed? true enabled? true clickable? true

After executing the click and catching the exception:

> Position: (826, 299), Dimensions: (16, 16)

So the element has not moved.

As you can see inner HTML is just one img:

```html
<div class="popupContent">
   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 100%; height: 100%;">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td align="right" style="vertical-align: top;"><button type="button" class="wl-popup-close-button" style="border-style: none; outline-style: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding: 0px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAQAAAC1+jfqAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAAAmJLR0QAAKqNIzIAAAAJcEhZcwAACxIAAAsSAdLdfvwAAAAHdElNRQfhCB8QKRBsEUJwAAAAn0lEQVQoz72RMQ7CMAwADwbgCSyhqmDpFj6AWqSOfIoH8BkGNsLGhiwG6NKJDvwBBoaExPCAeontu0SWA32F1HKTRawyucjK58PQ21LgvCIZjiU7DwbhzpQjBR0lbxw5LaXtlKCUl8ZKiAoapxkARkzCOU7NKMiMEzktdwxO5n9CxBVrGq18Xzh4bB/2SUWDYf+7qI1cxaRx5Sx1b7/0AYDRNbDgNXvDAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" class="gwt-Image" style="visibility: visible;"></button></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

So any suggestions as to why this is happening would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't clearly understand your problem. Is it just about an element that, sometimes, is not clickable ?

Answer (score 0):

Try induce java Scripts executor to click on the element with following xpath.

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='wl-popup-close-button']/img[@class='gwt-Image']"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case the [`<img>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) itself is not clickable and you need to click the parent [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) instead.

In XPath you can access the any element in the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) and its parents, children, siblings, etc.

So I would recommend amending your selector to point to the [parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/parent) button :

```
//img[@class='gwt-Image']/parent::button
```

and my expectation is that the click should be successful.

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)